# Python sys.stdin and subprocess stdout difference

Tags: python, types, subprocess, stdout, stdin

I currently have a larger problem at hand so I started by trying to match the smaller differences to see if that'll fix my issue.

In my program, I was using a pipe and iterating through that input through sys.stdin. I noticed it's type is `<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>`. I'm trying to avoid using a pipe and replaced my code to use `subprocess.run()` instead and noticed that the result has the type `<class 'str'>` instead.

This could be a really stupid question but I'm wondering why they're different and if I can get the subprocess stdout to be the same type as sys.stdin.

Using Python 3.7.5

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? Subprocess has changed in some recent versions. As a general statement, run() represents all the stdin/stdout all "gobbled up" and returned in a string whereas the PIPEs are used when there is a LOT of output. Generally, run() is used only if the output is limited.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.7.5, updated main post as well thanks I forgot to mention. I can't rely on PIPE since I actually need to run this process multiple times in different directories and process their outputs together. What I'm trying to run is a dry run of GNU make. Works as intended if using PIPE from cmd/terminal, but switching to run() and using the stdout from that produces a maximum recursion depth error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`subprocess.run` returns a `CompletedProcess` instance, with the collected stdout/stderr captured all at once.

If you want a stream, create a `Popen` instance, which will have `stdout` and `stderr` attributes that act like `sys.stdin`, and a `stdin` attribute that acts like `sys.stdout`. But beware pipe buffering/deadlock problems if you do anything fancy.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing apples and oranges. The *contents* of `sys.stdin` are `str` instances (though you can configure it to return `bytes`, somewhat painstakingly; `subprocess` on Python 3.x returns `bytes` unless you specify `text=True` or similar to decode those bytes into a `str`).

```
Python 3.7.2 (default, Jan 29 2019, 13:41:02) 
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> type(sys.stdin)
<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
>>> line = sys.stdin.readline()
fnord
>>> type(line)
<class 'str'>
>>> import subprocess
>>> s = subprocess.run(['true'], capture_output=True, text=True)
>>> type(s)
<class 'subprocess.CompletedProcess'>
>>> type(s.stdout)
<class 'str'>
```